# I am confused about a which clause

Tags: relative-clauses

> How would you decide **which are the likely winners among the runners** in the next race?

Does the sentence mean how would you decide the winners among the runners in the next race?

My question is whether the sentence (which are the likely winners among the runners) is a **clause** or is used to **describe the verb-decide**.

Comment: It's not about you deciding the winners; the outcome of the race will do that. It's about you guessing who you think is likely to win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words "which are the likely winners among the runners in the next race" are indeed a clause. There's a subject, "which", and that subject has a verb with tense, "are", so it's a clause.

In this case, the clause is functioning as a noun, the *object* of "decide".

Comment: I agree with this answer, but just to follow up on our thread from another post . . . What is the actual function of the clause? Is it "noun", or is it "object"? Or does it have multiple functions? I don't think that that's entirely clear from your last sentence.